# Xcode: indent code in a single shortcut

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'm using Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.2.

The point is that I'm largely tired of "running":

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + A
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + I

in order to indent the whole code.

So, I think I'm quite close to find the solution, creating my own shortcut on **IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist**.

```
<key>My Custom Shortcuts</key>
<dict> 
    <key>Indent Code In One Hit</key>
    <string>selectAll:, ....., moveLeft:</string>
</dict>
```

I have done a lot of test substituting '.....' with various commands (combining [this](https://gist.github.com/ryecroft/7433433)), but I can't find a solution yet.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to re-indent your code in anyway (without shortcut) ?

Comment: I think your bet is to write a macro, i.e use AppleScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by my self, without installing any unverified plugins.
I think that could be other solutions with higher performance.

1. Close Xcode
2. Edit **IDETextKeyBindingSet**

   ```
   sudo nano /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist
   ```

   Adding this:

   ```
   <key>My Custom Shortcuts</key>
   <dict> 
        <key>Custom - Indent Code In One Hit</key>
        <string>selectAll:, cut:, paste:</string>
   </dict>
   ```
3. Open Xcode, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + ; to open preferences
4. Key Bindings and filter by "Custom"
5. Assign you favourite key binding.

[image]

6. Exit from preferences, stir your code, try your new shortcut and feel the power!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [this](https://github.com/ThilinaHewagama/AutoIndentWithSave). It helps you re-indent code each time you Cmd + S

Comment: Didn't work for me. 
Issue #11 "Stopped working on Version 7.3"

Comment: Currently, I use the latest Xcode 7.3.1 and it still works well. (I'm using Objective - C)

Answer (score 0):

"Command + ]" will indent all the highlighted code.

Comment: This is not what he's looking for. This shifts the code to the right or left, while he is looking for a command to adjust/correct the indent.